# New keyboard has no sleep button

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate, xbindkeys

I got a new keyboard(Lenovo) but it has no sleep key which I use very frequently.

I have a script to do the suspension.

Can I take a rarely used key, like the Pause/Break key and cause it's pressing to put my computer in suspend mode?

I have installed xbindkeys.

Comment: settings, keyboard, custom keys. ctrl+alt+shft+anykeyuwnat usual is free. suspend command can be 

bash -i -c "systemctl suspend"
OR
 (need to install pm-utils AND run from a script with sudoers permissions)


bash pm-suspend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the command `systemctl suspend` to a shortcut key. You can try key combinations for yourself in the dialog for assigning shortcut keys: you will see which work and which cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Casually I discover some easteregg keys in my Lenovo Keyboard E490..

`SLEEP` = "Fn+4"
`PAUSE` = "Fn+p", among others..